# jquery and jqueryUI conflicting

Tags: jquery, recursion, jquery-ui

Is jquery 1.3.2 conflicting with jqueryui 1.8.4? I get the error "Too much recursion" (using the code below).

When I combine jquery 1.3.2 with jqueryui 1.7.2 I don't get this error, but it breaks my code...

Is there somewhere a reference table which jquery version works with which jqueryui code?

```
<html>
<head>
<title>This is the title</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.4/jquery-ui.min.js'></script>
</head>
<body>nothing here</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes there is a conflict between these versions -- 
and I got stuck because **Drupal** doesn't like JQuery newer than 1.3.2 -- I read somebody having the same issue because **Greasemonkey** doesn't work with any JQuery above 1.3.2 either.

I found this ticket:
http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/6689

There is a .zip file posted there with a modified version of the JQuery UI library.  I was getting this error while trying to use **ui.dialog** -- I just copied that part of the modified library into my code and it works.

Answer (score 5):

Can't you just include the 2 most recent versions? Works for me on a number of projects.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.5/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```